# How to insert into sql query string with a string derived from python list

Tags: python, sql

I have an example SQL query string like this:

```
query = "select * from myTbl where name in ('apple', 'pear')"
```

I need to replace `('apple', 'pear')` with any python list generated.

How I can insert any list into the SQL query string without hardcoded in. 
The code below does not work:

```
myList = ['apple', 'pear']
sList = ','.join(myList)
"select * from myTbl where name in ({})".format(sList)
```

It gives a query string `'select * from myTbl where name in (apple,pear)'`
What I need is a query string `"select * from myTbl where name in ('apple','pear')"`

Comment: https://bobby-tables.com/python

Comment: Dont use format  to format the query. Use parametrized queries and supply a tuple of values for your querystring with placeholdeers inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the quotes around each element:

```
sList = ','.join('\'' + i + '\'' for i in myList)
```